# How do I display this in a gsp page ${list.find{it.code==$otherlist.code}.Desc}

Tags: list, grails, gsp

How do I display something like this in a gsp page

${list.find{it.code==$otherlist.code}.Desc}

Comment: You need to provide more information.  What have you tried? What didn't work? Were there any errors?  What is the goal?  What classes are you using?  What's `list`? `otherList`? `Desc`?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try?

```
${list.find{it.code==otherlist.code}.Desc}
```